# Multiple GROUP BY and COUNT in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, group-by

My Sql structure :

```
CREATE TABLE collection (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY user_id (user_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE collection_link (
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  collection_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  configitem_id bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY IDX_7CDBB51F514956FD (collection_id),
  KEY IDX_7CDBB51F9D3DD91F (configitem_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE configitem (
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE user_account (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


ALTER TABLE collection
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_FC4D6532A76ED395 FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user_account (id),

ALTER TABLE collection_link
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_7CDBB51F514956FD FOREIGN KEY (collection_id) REFERENCES collection (id),
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_7CDBB51F9D3DD91F FOREIGN KEY (configitem_id) REFERENCES configitem (id);
```

Second, a user_account can add many configitems in collections and also can add the same items in collections as he want.

With that, I need to find the top configitems added in collections and avoid duplicate added by users in their collections. Aka if a user have 5 same configitems in one collection count only one... And that's my problem.

With that:

> SELECT id, SUM(num)  FROM (
>       SELECT l.configitem_id as id, COUNT(DISTINCT l.configitem_id) as num FROM collection_link l LEFT JOIN collection c9_ ON l.collection_id
>   = c9_.id  LEFT JOIN user_account u2_ ON c9_.user_id = u2_.id WHERE l.configitem_id = 1121 GROUP BY u2_.id, l.configitem_id
>       ) as cmpt;

I can receive the exact count for configitem 1121 but how to apply to all?

Because all my tests fail...

This works and takes top 25 added :

```
SELECT DISTINCT c2_.id AS id_0, count(c1_.id) AS sclr_1 
FROM collection_link c1_ 
LEFT JOIN configitem c2_ ON c1_.configitem_id = c2_.id 
LEFT JOIN collection c8_ ON c1_.collection_id = c8_.id 
LEFT JOIN user_account u9_ ON c8_.user_id = u9_.id 
GROUP BY c2_.id 
ORDER BY sclr_1 DESC LIMIT 25;
```

but takes duplicates.

Comment: Please edit your post and add the table definitions as text instead of the image.

Comment: Also post the result of your working query

Comment: done for defintions.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you need to aggregate by user and config item before taking the count. Or, simply do a `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT c2_.id AS id_0,
       COUNT(DISTINCT u9_.id) AS sclr_1 
FROM collection_link c1_ LEFT JOIN
     configitem c2_
     ON c1_.configitem_id = c2_.id LEFT JOIN
     collection c8_
     ON c1_.collection_id = c8_.id LEFT JOIN
     user_account u9_
     ON c8_.user_id = u9_.id 
GROUP BY c2_.id 
ORDER BY sclr_1 DESC
LIMIT 25;
```

Note that this version of the query does not need to join to the user table:

```
SELECT c2_.id AS id_0,
       COUNT(DISTINCT c8_.user_id) AS sclr_1 
FROM collection_link c1_ LEFT JOIN
     configitem c2_
     ON c1_.configitem_id = c2_.id LEFT JOIN
     collection c8_
     ON c1_.collection_id = c8_.id 
GROUP BY c2_.id 
ORDER BY sclr_1 DESC
LIMIT 25;
```

Comment: Oh Gordon, many thanks you save my day :) it's works perfectly ! missing DISTINCT in COUNT :o